# Clear formatting in range without using document.execCommand('removeFormat')

Tags: javascript

I want to allow a user to select, create a range, and then have javascript remove the underline on the range that the user selects. For example, If I have the code

```
<u> Hello, my name is Justin, and I have a question </u>
```

And the user selects "Justin, and I" and hits un-underline, would it be possible to change the HTML to:

```
<u> Hello, my name is </u> 

Justin, and I

<u> have a question </u>
```

or if the entire sentence is selected, have the entire  element deleted and replaced with normal text?

Comment: Why do you want to do that "without using `document.execCommand('removeFormat')"?

Comment: Note that this particular command comes with a lot of discrepancy in browsers: https://w3c.github.io/editing/docs/execCommand/#the-removeformat-command Which one would you like? I.e which elements should be stripped off for your case?

Answer (score 0):

**The solution has bugs if selected both underline and normal text at same time, i am trying to fix it.**

1. `getSelection()` to get selected text.
2. `getRangeAt(0)` get selected index in string, remember to `+3` because the length of `<u>` is 3.
3. Use `slice()` create new html and replace the old html.

```js
function selected() {
    let target = document.getSelection(),
        range, res
    if (target.toString() === '') return
    range = target.getRangeAt(0)
    if (range.commonAncestorContainer.parentElement.tagName != 'U') return
    res = range.commonAncestorContainer.parentElement.outerHTML
    let head = res.slice(0, range.startOffset + 3),
        middle = `</u>${target.toString()}<u>`,
        tail = res.slice(range.endOffset + 3)
    range.commonAncestorContainer.parentElement.outerHTML = head + middle + tail
}
document.onmouseup = selected;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <u>Hello, my name is Justin, and I have a question</u>
</body>
</html>
```